# Angular JS routing makes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

i got Django server with

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  url('^', IndexView.as_view(), name='index')
]
```

landing/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url('^.*', include("landing.urls"))
]
```

views.py

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'landing/header.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['meals'] = get_data()

    return context
```

header.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="KolyadaApp">

<div ng-view></div>
<a class="navbar-brand" ng-href="/landing">landing</a>
<a ng-href="#/menu">menu</a>
<a ng-href="#/week">week</a>
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */
var KolyadaApp = angular.module('KolyadaApp', ['ngRoute',    'ngResource']);

angular.
  module('KolyadaApp').
  config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', '$interpolateProvider',
    function config($locationProvider, $routeProvider, $interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');

    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: function(route) {

                console.log(route);

                return '/';
            }
        }).
        when('/menu', {
          templateUrl: '/menu.html'
        }).
        when('/week', {
          templateUrl: '/week.html'
        }).
        otherwise('/', {
            redirectTo:'/'
        });
}
]);
```

What I got: after loading page, I can do nothing with links, Console log periodically tells me about call stack overflow. And it hard to close the tab.

Well, after some time of searching answer, and placing '/' everywhere where I can, I decide to ask you. Please tell where I'm wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think issue is due to router? Looks straightforward enough

Comment: well, I don't except that I just use 'router' wrong, but this code is simple, and it doesn't work. I don't know, what to do and how to debug it, googling didn't give me answer. And the last thing I add to code was routing. if you see I tried to use function to debug =)

Comment: Understand...that last comment may help.. that problem didn't start until added router. That's why I asked. The `otherwise` looks wrong, try change to `otherwise({      redirectTo:'/'  })`

Comment: Oh...also doesn't make sense there is no template path in main route. Would mean you load page into itself. Try using one of the other templates on that one for now

Comment: I have encountered this error and the cause is a missing template. Please check if your templateUrls point to an existing one.

Comment: well I changed url path to /landing/templates/landing/menu.html in menu button, and got this django log 

[27/Jun/2016 17:55:23] "GET /landing/templates/landing/menu.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2453

but page still doesn't work, I also changed otherwise link as said above

Comment: may be there is a way to debug what happen when I'm routing?
btw. angular's directive **template** works correct

Comment: and also I add listeners on routing $locationChangeStart locationChangeSuccess and $routeChangeError, first of all invoked start listener, then success, after it page is stop working, I can't go to other links and in console i got **Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your issue, I believe:

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  url('^', IndexView.as_view(), name='index')
]
```

## landing/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url('^.*', include("landing.urls"))  # Circular reference
]
```

You're reloading `landing.urls` inside your include tag everytime you load `landing/urls.py`.

Did you mean for that line to be in `urls.py`? If so you'll need to alter one or both so they don't conflict (i.e. `^` and `^.*` both match an empty string).